# get results from queries stored in a table into its own result set?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

I have a table that has a varchar(max) column which contains a SQL query.  These queries were dynamically generated based off of values found in other tables.  Ultimately, I need to get the results of these queries (which are just simple count(*) statements) and join them with info from other tables.

Is it possible to get the results from the queries stored in the table without having to run them individually?

```
TableWithQueries

Query                                                ID         Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select Count(*) from somewhere Where someID = 18     01         Server01 Logins
Select Count(*) from somewhere Where someID = 13     02         Server08 Logins
Select Count(*) from somewhere Where someID = 49     03         Server23 Logins
```

I would like to get the results of those queries into some other table so I can join them with other columns.  Something like this:

```
QueryResults      Name                ID      SomeOtherInfo
----------------------------------------------------------------
48                Server01Logins      01      k393838dd
51                Server08Logins      02      b39848dff
99                Server23Logins      03      k394890dd
```

Comment: `SomeOtherInfo` is coming from same table or you need to join the result with some new table?

Comment: SomeOtherInfo is coming from another table.

Comment: you can then use the #FinalResult from the answer I have provided and join it to another table and get your final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there will be cleaner code than this but this should work.
Below query will execute your stored SQLs into a table (`#FinalResult`) which you can then join to another table (based on `ID`) to get the final result.

**Note:** I have used tables from `AdventureWorksDW2012` to form my `SELECT COUNT` queries.

```
     CREATE TABLE #test
    (
        Query VARCHAR(MAX) ,
        ID INT ,
        Name VARCHAR(100)
    );

INSERT INTO #test (   Query ,
                      ID ,
                      Name
                  )
VALUES (   'select count(*)  FROM dbo.DimAccount' , -- Query - varchar(max)
           1 ,                                      -- ID - int
           'Server01 Logins'                        -- Name - varchar(100)
       ) ,
    (   'select count(*)  FROM dbo.DimCustomer' , -- Query - varchar(max)
        2 ,                                       -- ID - int
        'Server08 Logins'                         -- Name - varchar(100)
    ) ,
    (   'select count(*)  FROM dbo.DimEmployee' , -- Query - varchar(max)
        3 ,                                       -- ID - int
        'Server09 Logins'                         -- Name - varchar(100)
    );



CREATE TABLE #Result
    (
        QueryResult INT --(assuming its only count)
        --,ID INT 
    );

CREATE TABLE #FinalResult
    (
        QueryResult INT --(assuming its only count)
        ,ID INT 
    );

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ID INT 
DECLARE @Count INT
DECLARE ResultCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT Query, ID
    FROM   #test;


OPEN ResultCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM ResultCursor
INTO @Sql, @id;

WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
    BEGIN



        INSERT INTO #Result 
        EXEC sp_executesql @Sql  
        FETCH NEXT FROM ResultCursor
        INTO @Sql, @Id;

        INSERT INTO #FinalResult (   QueryResult ,
                                     ID
                                 )
        SELECT QueryResult, @id FROM #Result

        DELETE FROM #result

    END;

CLOSE ResultCursor;
DEALLOCATE ResultCursor;

SELECT *
FROM   #FinalResult;

DROP TABLE #test;
DROP TABLE #Result;
DROP TABLE #FinalResult;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try this out tomorrow when I get into work.  It looks like it'll work; from what I've gathered I don't think there is a way to do this without using a cursor or while loop.

Comment: @MS204 Happy to help. I am also not sure if there is a straight forward way of doing this without loop or cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a the `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` documentation, it sounds like what you may be looking for.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html